# how to pass a QuerySet instance to serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using raw sql (using orm is working) for fetching products and i'm getting this error

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `ProductSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `tuple` 
instance.
Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'.
```

This is the get function:

```
def get(self, request, store_id, format=None):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        user = request.user
        check_auth = get_object_or_404(
            Store, id=store_id, owner_id=user.id)
        if check_auth != None:
            connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM products')
            products = cursor.fetchall()
            serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
    raise Http404
```

and here's the serializer class:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
category = CategorySerializer()

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['id', 'store_id', 'name', 'summary',
              'description', 'category', 'main_image', 'price', 'offer_price', 'cost', 
    'available_quantity']
```

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but does the `Product` class have a `name` field?
EDIT: saw just now that you're not actually passing a queryset to the serializer, but a tuple.

Comment: Product has a name. how to pass the object to the serializer not in tuple ?

Comment: You need to either write a custom serializer (not a `ModelSerilalizer`) or just get the objects without using raw sql. Is there a reason you're not using `Product.objects.filter()`?

Comment: it's a project for database course, using raw sql is a need. could you please tell how to do the custom serializer for this class ?

Comment: You CAN'T pass raw SQL data to modelSerializer like that. ORM - as name suggest (Object-relational mapping) maps your "sql response" to the model instances. The only way out for this is to create custom serializer. I suggest You to map sql to json and create JSON serializer for this;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django **ModelSerializer** will work only in the case of **QuerySet** object retrieved from models.  Executing queries using a connection object will give result in Python native data types like **List** and **Tuple** for which **ModelSerializer** will not work. So, in this case, `cursor.fetchall()` will give the list of `tuples`, and each tuple consists of a relational DB row.  So to serialize these data types instead of **ModelSerializer** use just **Serializer**. Below code snippet will give the detail idea on **SerializerMethodField**.

View.py

```py
class RawQueryDjango(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('select * from products_usermodel')
        res = cursor.fetchall()
        serializer = RawQuerySerializer(res, many=True)
        print(serializer.data)
        return Response({'detail': serializer.data})
```

Serializer.py

```py
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer, ModelSerializer, SerializerMethodField


class RawQuerySerializer(Serializer):
    name = SerializerMethodField()
    last_name = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return obj[1]

    def get_last_name(self, obj):
        return obj[2]    # index value at which last_name in tuple
```

This will give the following response. In raw query execution no interaction with model has been done.

```py
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "name": "abc",
            "last_name": "sadfasd"
        },
        {
            "name": "asasasd",
            "last_name": "werwe"
        },
        {
            "name": "asdafa",
            "last_name": "1231weasd"
        },
        {
            "name": "sh",
            "last_name": "patil"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Akash Pagar, it's working. Just the obj[1] should be obj[0].
Thanks again.